# showing and hiding entitiy in GameGuru MAX (Lua)

Tags: lua, scripting

I am brand new to LUA and I am trying to show a hidden entity but I think I am doing something wrong. I can call the sound effect but not the entity?

Any help greatly appreciated

```
    g_plrinzone = {}

function plrinzone_init(e)
end

function plrinzone_main(e)
 if g_Entity[e]['plrinzone']==1 then
  PlaySound(e,0)
  Show(e,lightning)
    Destroy(e)
  PerformLogicConnections(e)
 end
end
```

Comment: What is the game? roblox, gta, computercraft, something else?

Comment: I am using game guru MAX